# How can I load two json files with script, without one script overwriting the other?

Tags: javascript, html, tabulator

I have a html file, which shows two Tabulator tables. Table 1 is connected to saveFile1.json and table 2 to saveFile2.json. My problem is, that the `<script>` from saveFile2.json overwrites the `<script>` from saveFile1.json, so that both tables show the content from saveFile2.json. How can I fix this? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyCSS.css" >
        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/tabulator-tables/dist/js/tabulator.js"></script>
    </head>
    
<body>

<table>
    <td>
        <div id="table1"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="saveFile1.json"></script>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="table2"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="saveFile2.json"></script>
    </td>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tabulatorTables.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're asking about Javascript but you show no code?

Comment: Use different variable names and/or modules.

Comment: @CharlesEF Last time I had a simular problem, I just needed to switch positions of `<script>` tags in the html file to make it work. So my thought is, that the solution could be simular this time.

Comment: @jabaa Do you know a module, that could solve my "double-json-problem"?

Comment: You should load the scripts as modules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules. You should use correct naming conventions. `saveFile1.json` can't be a JSON file. It's a JavaScript file. You should name it `saveFile1.js`.

Comment: Hey @jabaa With the solution below from Michael O'Keefe, I now realised what specific vars you meant with "different variable names". So you actually already had the right solution. That's why I would like to thank you, too! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im gonna guess (since you dont provide a jsfiddle) that your json files consist of

```
saveFile1.json : var data = [ ... ];
saveFile2.json : var data = [ ... ];
```

and you use the same data variable on each of your Tabulators.

Hence, last saveFile*.json loaded, wins.

Use different variable names (data1 and data2) and apply them to each Tabulator (table1.setData(data1); table2.setData(data2) ) specifically.

Comment: Hey, it's you again :D Because this problem is so simular to the last one from a view days ago, I thought about writing you a PN. But sadly a PN feature doesn't exist on this website :( In case I have a problem in the future: Is there a way I could contact you personally? I mean, of course just if you are ok with that. And about your solution for this problem: OMG, you were so right! That was it. I looked at them: Both var had the same name. Changed them: BOOM, it works. Again: Thank you very much!

Comment: Its better for the community to do it here, that way ppl with similar problems in the future can search and find the answer.